# Ruby mongoDB and large documents

Tags: ruby, mongodb, gridfs, bson

I have a populated mongoDB.

Now I need to add huge amounts of additional data to my documents (log file data). This data exceeds the BSON size limit.

> Document too large: This BSON document is limited to 16777216 bytes. (BSON::InvalidDocument)

A simplified example of my situation would look like this:

```
cli = MongoClient.new("localhost", MongoClient::DEFAULT_PORT)
db = cli.db("testdb")
coll = db.collection("test")

data = {:name => "Customer1", :data1 => "some value", :log_file => "A" * 17_000_000}

coll.save data
```

1. What is the best way to add this huge amount of data?
2. Could I use GridFS to store those files and link the GridFS-file-handle to the correct document?

   1. Could I then access the GridFS-file during queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paragraph about *document growth* finally solved my question. (Found by following Konrad's link.)

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-model-operations/#data-model-document-growth

What I am now basically doing is this:

```
cli = MongoClient.new("localhost", MongoClient::DEFAULT_PORT)
db = cli.db("testdb")
coll = db.collection("test")
grid = Grid.new db

#store data
id = grid.put "A"*17_000_000
data = {:name => "Customer1", :data1 => "some value", :log_file => id}
coll.save data

#access data
cust = coll.find({:name => "Customer1"})
id = cust.first["log_file"]
data = grid.get id
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest two approaches:

**GridFS** with instructions here https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/wiki/GridFS

- **Advantages:** uses already existing service(mongodb) to store files so presumably easiest to implement/ cheapest since you already have the infrastructure.
- **Disadvantage:** Not necesarilly the best use of an in-memory DB, especially if it's used for other storage as well.

**S3** -  Store links to a hosted data service (such as Amazon S3) which is designed for file storage (redundant, replicated and highly available). In this case you just upload the files and store a pointer to their S3 location in your DB.

- **Advantage** Keeps your DB leaner, probably cheaper since you keep your mongo machines optimised for doing mongo things (i.e. high-memory) and take advantage of the really cheap file storage on S3 as well as the near-infinite scalability.
- **Disadvantage** Harder to implement since you need to design your own code to do this. Though there may be off the shelf solutions somewhere.

Some more useful discussion on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15030532/mongodb-as-file-storage)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can split up your document and reference them. See this SO post: [syntax for linking documents in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471633/syntax-for-linking-documents-in-mongodb)